# Show zones only if timeframe is less than H4

Tags: pine-script

I'm using FX Market Sessions script, but I want to show the session zones only if the current timeframe is below H4. How do I do that?

```
bool show = timeframe.multiplier >= 1 and timeframe.multiplier <= 60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert timeframe to minutes then compare the result.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_tfInMinutes() => 
    _tfInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

is_show = f_tfInMinutes() < 240

plot(is_show ? close : na)
```